# Is it correct to include data as a key name in JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, standards

I am consuming an API that is providing a JSON payload.  One of the properities in the JSON is actually a data element, thus I'm unable to de-serialize the payload without adding additional classes.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
      "company": "ABC Inc.",
      "packages": {
          "$package1": {
          "code": "$package1",
          "name": "Foo",
          "price": 1000
        },
        "$package2": {
          "code": "$package2",
          "name": "Bar",
          "price": 2000
        },
        "$package3": {
          "code": "$package3",
          "name": "Another",
          "price": 3000
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to serialize using Newtonsoft.Json with the following classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string company { get; set; }
    public Packages packages { get; set; }
}

public class Packages
{
    public Package1 package1 { get; set; }
    public Package2 package2 { get; set; }
    public Package3 package3 { get; set; }
}

public class Package1
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}

public class Package2
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}

public class Package3
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}
```

Using this approach I can de-serialize using Newtonsoft.Json, but if "package4" is added later, then it requires me to make a code change.

Should I push back on the developer of this API and insist on an array of packages, rather than how it is currently implemented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using a `Dictionary<>`, for example:

```
public partial class Rootobject
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Package> Packages { get; set; }
}

public partial class Package
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Price { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialise like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

And use it like this:

```
foreach (var element in result.Packages)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Package: {element.Key} has name {element.Value.Name}");
}
```

Which would output:

```
Package: $package1 has name Foo
Package: $package2 has name Bar
Package: $package3 has name Another
```

Comment: OP seems to ask about best practices instead of a way of handling the current JSON payload. Your solution integrates smoothly with the current state but should we not try making that part better too as it is feasible in this case?

Comment: @Siavas In what way is the JSON and my code not "best practice"? (and thanks for the DV)

Comment: This is a great answer and fixes my problem given the providers current API.  However, I will still be asking for them to change the JSON to a more acceptable format.  Can anyone verify that the above JSON breaks with the standard?  **Is there a standard?**

Comment: @KyleBarnes There is no "standard", and the JSON is perfectly reasonable. Personally i wouldn't ask for it to be changed.

Comment: Have elaborated on this in my answer (thanks too). Your code would best practice if that API could not be changed, but as @KyleBarnes mentioned, it can so making it more coherent by removing the packages numbers would do better.

Comment: @Siavas But there is *nothing wrong with the JSON*. I have seen and used this format of data many times.

Comment: @KyleBarnes there are standards for JSON format such as for [OData](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/json-format/) protocol, a standardised way of creating RESTful APIs backed by Microsoft, but in your case there seems not to be any restriction. It is still better to consider **best practices** as that API slightly defies YAGNI and DRY principles. One could argue this is an overkill for such scenario but it would surely help your API provider write better code in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Having such duplicated classes would reduce the reusability of your code significantly. This can better be achieved with a list of packages instead:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string company { get; set; }
    public List<Package> packages { get; set; }
}
```

And your Package class:

```
public class Package
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow to have many `Package` objects for one company. The only drawback is that you have to ask for changing it to an array there as well, but for considering best practices that would do best as package numbers do not seem to be required. Ideally you would have JSON payload received as:

```
{
      "company": "ABC Inc.",
      "packages": [
        {
          "name": "Foo",
          "price": 1000
        },
        {
          "name": "Bar",
          "price": 2000
        },
        {
          "name": "Another",
          "price": 3000
        }
    ]
}
```

And maybe get an Id as well if `name` is not unique.

Comment: This would throw an exception as a `List<>` requires an array element.

Comment: It would, but as OP is able to ask the API provider to change his JSON structure this would be a neater way of sending and storing these objects.

Comment: But there is no need to change the JSON, see my answer.